# MATLAB conversion from mW to dBm

Tags: matlab

Determine the power of a signal in **dBm** if absolute value is **100mW**.

The following code gives an error:

```
m Line: 1 Column: 6
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Code:

```
u=100mW;
10*log(10)(u)+30
```

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dbconversion.html

Comment: `log10(u)`? this is basic syntax, please read the docs, `log(10)(u)` is invalid

Comment: @Ander Biguri, It doesn't work with log10(u) neither.

Comment: `u=100mW;` is also invalid.

Comment: Sorry, you need to understand how programming/computers works. `u=100mw` is worng syntax

Comment: Could you show the right syntax?

Comment: No............ Just get a book.... or a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log10.html <-- how to use log10 function

and the proper code is:

```
u=100; %mW
solution = 10*log10(u/1000)+30;
```

you can skip division and adding 30 and calculate it as:

```
u=100; %mW
solution = 10*log10(u);
```

You can not mix numbers and units as matlab doesn't understand what watts, metres etc are.

Comment: Why is yours 'u' variable in 'mW' and not in 'W'?

Comment: Ohh that's true, forgot to divide by 1000. Corrected version in the answer

Comment: So, in the first line, 'u=100;' is actually in 'W', right?

Comment: No. It is in mW but you add 30 after logarithm. check: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/mW_to_dBm.htm and http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/Watt_to_dBm.htm

Comment: In your first code, why do you divide 'u' by 1000 if it isn't in 'W'?

Comment: Could you show one example with 'W->dB' conversion and also one example with different prefix in 'Watt'? Example for 'pW'.